# Why i am getting exception as There is no index named

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I am using Raven Db in my project problem is that it is throwing exception that
**There is no index named** but i have created index and i can see in raven studio. and am using correct name no spelling mismatch.

I am creating indexes in different namespaces each class contain 5 indexes for grouping tickets  by day, by month-year, by Quarter,by year and one for from first to last ticket it was initial index in all namespaces

initially there was no first 4 indexes and i was getting data in my program for initial index. now i have added these grouping indexes. I can see indexes in Raven studio and result also for all indexes but in program i am able to call only an initial index and not new 4 indexes in all namespaces Error message is **There is no index named**

plz suggest how to fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: which client and server versions are you using?

Comment: i am using version 2.5

Comment: I mean which build? I've seen a similar error lately

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply actually yesterday i have solved problem. Actually problem is that Ravendb not creates index when we recreate index so. I tried deleting DB and create new DB now its working with all indexes

Answer (score 0):

Does your index name contains an underscore `_`? They will be replaced with forward slashes. E.g. a static index named `BlogPosts_PostsCountByTag` will be queried with `BlogPosts/PostsCountByTag` (example taken from [Defining a static index](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/static-indexes/defining-static-index))